# How to remove this space?

Tags: html, html-table

In this image :

[image]

The code of this page is :

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
  <tr >
    <td align="center">
        <form method='post' name='recherche' id='formulaire' class="formulaire" >
            <article class='module width_2_quarter_no_height'>
                <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                        <header><h3><?php echo _getText("main.accueil.onglet.evenement.critere.titre"); ?></h3></header>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                        <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
                            <tr>
                                <td class="labelstyle">
                                    <?php echo _getText('main.accueil.tableau_bord.Titre'); ?>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input class="inputlong" type="text" name="event_titre" id="event_titre" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="labelstyle">
                                    <?php echo _getText('main.accueil.onglet.evenement.critere.type'); ?>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <select id="event_type" class="selectnormal">
                                        <option><?php echo _getText('main.accueil.onglet.evenement.critere.type.select'); ?></option>
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="labelstyle">
                                    <?php echo _getText('main.accueil.onglet.evenement.critere.redacteur'); ?>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <select id="event_redacteur" class="selectnormal">
                                        <option><?php echo _getText('main.accueil.onglet.evenement.critere.redacteur.select'); ?></option>
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="labelstyle"><?php echo _getText('main.accueil.onglet.evenement.critere.datedebut'); ?></td>
                                <td>
                                    <table width="250px" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td><input class="inputcourt" type="text" name="event_date_deb" id="event_date_deb" /></td>
                                            <td align="center" class="labelstyle"><?php echo _getText('main.accueil.onglet.evenement.critere.datefin'); ?></td>
                                            <td><input class="inputcourt" type="text" name="event_date_fin" id="event_date_fin" /></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                   </tr>
                   <tr>
                    <td>
                        <table width="90%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <fieldset>
                                        <legend>&nbsp;<em><span class="labelstyle"><?php echo _getText('main.accueil.onglet.evenement.critere.tache'); ?></span></em></legend>
                                        <table border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td class="labelstyle"><?php echo _getText('main.accueil.onglet.evenement.critere.type'); ?></td>
                                                <td class="labelstyle"><input type="radio" id="rb_tous" name="type_tache" value="0" /><?php echo _getText('main.accueil.onglet.evenement.filtre.tous'); ?></td>
                                                <td class="labelstyle"><input type="radio" id="rb_param" name="type_tache" value="1" checked /><?php echo _getText('main.accueil.onglet.evenement.critere.parametrage'); ?></td>
                                                <td class="labelstyle"><input type="radio" id="rb_redac" name="type_tache" value="2" /><?php echo _getText('main.accueil.onglet.evenement.critere.redaction'); ?></td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                        <table border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" width="100%">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td width="5%">
                                                    <span class="labelstyle"><?php echo _getText('main.accueil.onglet.evenement.critere.intitule'); ?></span>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <select id="tache_intitule" class="selectnormalLong">
                                                        <option><?php echo _getText('main.accueil.onglet.evenement.critere.tache.select'); ?></option>
                                                    </select>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </fieldset>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td align="center">
                        <input type="button" name="btnValider" id="btnValider" value="<?php echo _getText('Bouton.valider'); ?>" class="boutonstyle"  />
                        <input type="reset" name="btnReset" id="btnReset" value="<?php echo _getText('main.bouton.effacer'); ?>" class="boutonstyle" />
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
            </article>
        </form>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

So how to remove the space I encircled to red ?

Comment: Try not to Use tables for design 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/83073/why-not-use-tables-for-layout-in-html'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always use css.  In your

```
<fieldset style="margin-top: -20px">...
```

I'm guessing css somewhere is probably affecting it.  It's hard to tell without being able to see all your css.

Please note I'm not advocating inline style attributes...it's just a quick way to show that it is probably your css that is causing the space to be there.